# Node.js Passport LocalStrategy login freeze if the user and login is right

Tags: node.js, passport-local

Following the course on https://ide.c9.io/learnwithcolt/webdevbootcamp

Authentication - AuthDemo folder

My code:

```
var express               = require("express"),
    mongoose              = require("mongoose"),
    passport              = require("passport"),
    bodyParser            = require("body-parser"),
    LocalStrategy         = require("passport-local"),
    passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose"),
    User                  = require("./models/user")

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/auth_demo_app");

var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use(require("express-session")({
    secret: "This is my secret sentence",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());


//=========
// ROUTES
//=========

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("home");
});

app.get("/secret", function(req, res){
    res.render("secret");
})

//AUTH ROUTES
//show signup form
app.get("/register", function(req, res){
   res.render("register") ;
});

//handling user sign up
app.post("/register", function(req, res){
    req.body.username
    req.body.password
    User.register(new User({username:  req.body.username}), req.body.password, function(err, user){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return res.render("register");
        }
        passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
            res.render("./secret");
        });
    });

});


//LOGIN ROUTES
//render login form
app.get("/login", function(req, res) {
   res.render("login");
}),

//login logic
//middleware
app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", {
    succesRedirect: "./secret",
    failureRedirect: "/login"
    }), function(req, res){
});




app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function() {
    console.log("The AuthDemo Server has started!");
});
```

The login routes works fine if the username + password is wrong, the app redirect againt to the login form.

But if the username + password is fine the browser freeze and keeep saying "Waiting for " until displays this code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'> 
    <title>Error 502 - Bad Gateway</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.c9.io/errors/style.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
    .error_content {
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.23);
        padding: 10px;
        width: 641px;
        margin: 25px 0;
        display: none;
    }

    #error-msg {
        display: block;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body class="errorUnknown light">
    <div id="wrapper">
      <h1>Error 502 - Bad Gateway</h1>
      <div class="error_content" id="error-msg">
          <p>Please click <a href="javascript:location.reload(true)">here</a> to try again, if the issue persists please contact <a href="https://c9.io/support">support</a></p>
      </div>

      <a href="http://status.c9.io">Status Page</a> |
      <a href="https://c9.io/support">Support</a> |
      <a href="https://c9.io/dashboard.html">Dashboard</a> |
      <a href="https://c9.io">Home</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Maybe the original is code is outdated? Or I need to use a specific version of passport?**

User Model

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose")

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   username: String,
   password: String
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Comment: Can you show the code for the User model please? I think the problem is in how you’re setting up Passport but need to see that to be sure.

Comment: User Model posted, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a simple typo to me, unless you've copied your code wrong:

```
app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", {
    succesRedirect: "./secret",
    failureRedirect: "/login"
    }), function(req, res){
});
```

Note "successRedirect" is missing an 's'.

Comment: I can't believe it. Right answer, thanks a lot. Why node, or passport didn't give me any warning?

Comment: @fedeteka well, it's JavaScript.  The object is arbitrary, and Passport (and node) have no way to know that you meant a different key.  Remember that config object is just *one* way to setup the behavior, so I imagine under the hood Passport sees you don't have a successRedirect key and so assumes you're handling the success result differently.

Comment: Thanks Paul! New info for me.It makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Please compare my user.js model with your own.

Here is a code:

```html
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

// User Schema
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
 username: {
  type: String,
  index:true
 },
 password: {
  type: String
 },
 email: {
  type: String
 },
 name: {
  type: String
 }
});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports.createUser = function(newUser, callback){
 bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
     bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
         newUser.password = hash;
         newUser.save(callback);
     });
 });
}

module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback){
 var query = {username: username};
 User.findOne(query, callback);
}

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
 User.findById(id, callback);
}

module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback){
 bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch) {
     if(err) throw err;
     callback(null, isMatch);
 });
}
```

If you want I can upload full code with all files for Node.js Passport Login System. Just let me know

Comment: thanks, I added my User Model code but on the sample folder on https://ide.c9.io/learnwithcolt/webdevbootcamp  the User Model is more simple. I guess you use another system. I don't know about "var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');" by example

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the OP's question.